# How to get the bits of a "double" as a "long"

Tags: .net, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I would like to manipulate the bitwise representation of floating-point numbers in C#. BinaryWriter and BinaryReader do it this way:

```
public virtual unsafe void Write(double value)
{
    ulong num = *((ulong*) &value);
    ...
}
public virtual unsafe double ReadDouble()
{
    ...
    ulong num3 = ...;
    return *((double*) &num3);
}
```

Is there a way to do this without unsafe code, and without the overhead of actually using BinaryWriter and BinaryReader?

Comment: If you are concerned about speed, using a union approach is about three times faster as calling the `BitConverter` APIs in my quick tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you trying to avoid unsafe code altogether, or do you just want an alternative to those specific methods on `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter`?

You could use [`BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx) and [`BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble.aspx), which are designed to do exactly what you need, although I think they use the same unsafe conversion behind-the-scenes as the `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` methods.

Comment: Good answer! I wonder how I missed that one when I looked up BitConverter. I avoid unsafe code where possible so I can re-use code in e.g. Silverlight, but I like to use the fastest possible verifiable code.

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to use a custom struct with explicit layout that defines both a `long` and a `double` at offset 0.  This is equivalent to a `union` in C.

Something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct DoubleLongUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public long Long;
    [FieldOffset(0)] 
    public double Double;
}
```

Then use this:

```
var union = new DoubleLongUnion();
union.Double = 1.234d;
var longBytes = union.Long;
```

This will avoid any unsafe code and should perform pretty fast too as you perform the conversion on the stack.

I haven't tried/compiled this but I reckon it should work :)

**EDIT**

I just tried this and it works.  The value of `longBytes` above is 4608236261112822104.

Some other values:

```
0d              -> 0L
double.NaN      -> -2251799813685248L
double.MinValue -> -4503599627370497L
double.MaxValue -> 9218868437227405311L
```

Here's a method that does what you want:

```
public static long DoubleToLong(double d)
{
    return new DoubleLongUnion { Double = d }.Long;
}
```

Comment: In many ways unions are a form of unsafe code, but that is a nice solution :)

Comment: I don't think there's anything particularly unsafe here.  At least not according to the unverifiable meaning of `unsafe` in C#.  I think unsafe is a misnomer in .NET really.

Comment: @Drew - IIRC at least one framework (it might be CF, SL or MF) refuses to touch unions due their nature.

Comment: (don't get me wrong; it is a great answer - and I'll be back tomorrow to +1; all out today)

Comment: @Marc, I agree in principle about unions.  However I found this particular technique in the source code of the .NET framework!  I certainly have never missed having a `union` keyword in C#, but it's nice to know you can pull this trick out to solve problems like this when you need to.  Using unions in place of the polymorphism that the type system provides is bound to create some dodgy data.

Comment: @Drew, oh I agree. In fact I tried to use *exactly* this approach to avoid some `unsafe` code in my pet OSS library; I wish I could remember which framework rejected it, and exactly how. Probably Silverlight - SL is fussy.

Comment: @Marc, do you mean that the framework introspected your struct at runtime and threw an exception when loading it?  That be crazy.  I wish I could remember what part of the .NET framework I saw this technique used in.  I think it was probably somewhere in WPF or WCF.

Comment: @drew it would have been either a compiler or peverify issue. Maybe one of them simply omits the layout attribute? I can't remember off-hand.

Comment: But a union definitely isn't *entirely* safe; there's some freaky things you can do, especially if you deliberately don't make things quite line up straight ;) no more or less safe than doing the same via byte[] abuse, though.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `byte[] BitConverter.GetBytes(double)` and `long BitConverter.ToInt64(byte[],int)` (passing 0 as the start-index), but *internally* IIRC these use unsafe code, plus have the overhead of an array. Pick your poison...

Comment: Good enough for me, I guess. I see BitConverter also has a byte[]->long converter that is probably faster than combining the bytes manually.

Comment: I reckon you can do this without any API calls or unsafe code.