# C# How to extract bytes from double

Tags: c#, double, byte, long-integer

How can I extract bytes from `double` type. I know it has 8 bytes, just like `long`. How can I create a `long` variable that has the same bytes as the `double` has.

```
double a = 1.5;
long b = (long)a; // <- this returns 1
// i want to get this: 0 01111111111 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
//which is 4609434218613702656 as long (I guess :) )
```

How can I do this quickly, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the bits of a "double" as a "long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475611/how-to-get-the-bits-of-a-double-as-a-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it like this

```
double a = 1.5;
long l = BitConverter.ToInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(a), 0);
```

It will be `4609434218613702656`

As @harold suggested

```
var l2 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(a);
```

is possible too

Comment: BitConverter also has DoubleToInt64Bits though