# Check whether two floating-point values are identical

Tags: c#, .net, double

In C#, how can I write a method `bool AreSame(double x, double y)` that determines whether two `double` values are not only *equal* but also *identical*?

I'm aware of one case where two `double` values compare equal (whether using `==` or the `Equals` method) but aren't identical:

```
var x = 0D;
var y = double.NegativeZero;
Console.WriteLine(x == y);        // True
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));   // True
Console.WriteLine(AreSame(x, y)); // Desired output: False
```

And I'm aware of one case where two `double` values are identical but compare unequal when using `==`:

```
var x = double.NaN;
var y = double.NaN;
Console.WriteLine(x == y);        // False
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y));   // True
Console.WriteLine(AreSame(x, y)); // Desired output: True
```

The following `AreSame` implementation covers both cases, but (1) it requires .NET 7 or later—is there an implementation that works on all versions of .NET?—and (2) I don't know whether there are cases it doesn't handle:

```
bool AreSame(double x, double y) =>
    x.Equals(y) && double.IsNegative(x) == double.IsNegative(y);
```

---

The question [Comparing double values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp) is not a duplicate because it asks why two seemingly equal values compare unequal. In my case, I want `AreSame` to return `false` for unequal values no matter how small the difference.

In response to duplicate close votes: The question [C# How to extract bytes from double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723757/c-sharp-how-to-extract-bytes-from-double) is not a duplicate because (1) it asks a different question, and (2) it may be possible to check whether two `double` values are identical without extracting and comparing their bytes. An answer to this question doesn't necessarily answer that question.

Comment: I thought `(int)x == (int)y` would work but it doesn't (bytes are bytes I thought). `BitConverter.GetBytes(x).SequenceEqual(BitConverter.GetBytes(y))` does work though, it retrieves the underlying bytes of the doubles and compares them.